# Cinlar, Probability and Stochastic, Ch.2 ex. 4.14

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have this exercise (Cinlar, Ch.2 ex. 4.14 ):

> Let $T$ be a positive random variable and define a stochastic process $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ by setting, for each $\omega$ $$ X_t(\omega) = \begin{cases} 
>           0 & t< T(\omega) \\
>           1 & t\ge T(\omega) 
>        \end{cases}
>    $$
>   Show that $X$ and $T$ determine each other.

So I have to find two measurable functions $f,g$ such that \begin{align*} 
X &=  f \circ T \\ 
T &=  g \circ X
\end{align*}

the first one is easy. I have some problems with the second:
\begin{align*} 
\varphi: 2^{\mathbb{R}_+} &\longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}_+ \\ 
x &\longmapsto  \inf\{t \in \mathbb{R}_+ : x_t = 1\}
\end{align*}

I have that $T = \varphi \circ X$, so I'd like to say that $\varphi$ is measurable. I have that $$\varphi^{-1}(\alpha,+\infty) = \{x \in 2^{\mathbb{R}_+} : x_t = 0 \; \forall t\in[0, \alpha] \}$$
If what I've said till now is right, how can I show that this set is measurable in the product space? Thanks

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments this set is *not* measurable in $2^{\mathbb{R}_+}$. But the deterministic function $\varphi$ needs to have as domain the measurable space associated to the stochastic process $X$, which is $2^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ with its product $\sigma$-algebra... How can I solve this?

Comment: Your set actually *isn't* a measurable subset of $2^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ or, for that matter $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}_+}$. It's a measurable subset of the space of right-continous functions from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (basically because continuity allows you to change your statement to a statement about countably many points in times).

Comment: @WoolierThanThou ok, as I suspected. But now? The stochastic process $X$ takes values in $2^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ with its product $\sigma$-algebra...

Comment: Well, yes. But $X$ *also* takes values in the right-continuous functions, and you need this perspective in order to pick out what $T$ is.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou What is the $\sigma$-algebra on the space of right-continuous functions?

Comment: The trace $\sigma$-algebra of the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Ok, now I get it. But still I'm quite dubious about the feasibility of this change of space.

Comment: The book defines the codomain of a stochastic process to be exactly the product space of the space the single random variables are defined upon. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: I mean... you can check that $\{x\in \{0,1\}^{[0,\infty)}| x_t=0\forall t\leq \alpha\}$ isn't a product measurable set. However, labelling $C_r$ the subset of right continuous functions, you see that $\{x\in \{0,1\}^{[0,\infty)}| x_t=0 \forall t\leq \alpha\}\cap C_r=\{x\in \{0,1\}^{[0,\infty)}| x_{t_n}=0 \forall t_n\in [0,\alpha]\cap \mathbb{Q}\}\cap C_r,$ and the latter set is clearly the intersection of a product measurable set and $C_r$, hence in the trace algebra.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Ok, I understood that. So what I gather is that there is no way to prove determinabilty using the product $\sigma$-algebra (not its trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shown that $T$ is determined by $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Q}_+}$ (and a fortiori by $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$). I take the same function $\varphi$, but now I define it over $2^{\mathbb{Q}_+}$
\begin{align*} 
\varphi: 2^{\mathbb{Q}_+} &\longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}_+ \\ 
x &\longmapsto  \inf\{t \in \mathbb{Q}_+ : x_t = 1\}
\end{align*}

Now, it is evident that $T = \varphi \circ (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Q}_+}$, since $\mathbb{Q}_+$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_+$, it remains to show that $\varphi$ is $\mathscr{P}(\{0,1\})^{\mathbb{Q}_+}$-measurable.
But this is true because, in fact, since $\mathbb{Q}_+$ is countable, we have that $\mathscr{P}(\{0,1\})^{\mathbb{Q}_+} = \mathscr{P}(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Q}_+})$, and therefore every numerical function over $2^{\mathbb{Q}_+}$ is measurable.